# What is Jquery and how to make animation for website

Tags: jquery, animation, web

Looking for some good tutorials to learn JQuery. I want to learn animations used in websites some suggestions please. thank you!

My basic problem is animation on some sites they say use JS and on some they say JQ

Comment: This isn't really a question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please use google for such questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I provided some fairly basic annotated code below, adapted from W3schools example. Try to understand it, try to change it so it moves left to right, not just width and height, and you will get a hold of it.

```js
 function animate() {
     //jQuery selector: select all div elements into var 'div',
     //it then becomes a container of this collection with a
     //number of methods to manipulate it
     //see https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp
     var div = $("div"); 
        
     startAnimation(); // hoisting, see below
        
     function startAnimation(){
        //animate until height is 100
        div.animate({height: 100}, "slow");
        //then animate until width is 100
        div.animate({width: 100}, "slow");
        //then animate until height is 50 
        div.animate({height: 50}, "slow");
        //then animate until width is 50 and call itself after
        div.animate({width: 50}, "slow", startAnimation);
     }
}
animate();
```

```css
.box-a {
  left:10px;top:50px;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  position:absolute;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box-a"></div>
```

Comment: thank you for your help brother now I got it how it works.

Comment: YW. Please, please, try to expand your question - what did you try, why searching or other web sites did not work for you, and also what type of animation you need, and your question might have a chance to stay and help others - you get plus points for it and others will appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is a Javascript library that, simplify some tasks for web developpers.
for example  accessing if you want to access an element in Javascript by its ID you will use

```
var myelement = document.getElementById(myelementID)
```

the simplified version in JQuery would be

```
var myelement= $('#myelementID');
```

I would suggest the code academy learning path if you like learning by practicing : https://www.codecademy.com/learn/jquery
 otherwise  you can consult https://learn.jquery.com/ .
Concerning animation I would highly recommend the animate.css library: https://daneden.github.io/animate.css it is very easy to animate html component with it ( you just need to add the animation class to your component class attribute) and the cool thing is that you can do that to add animations dynamically using JQuery (for example when you click a button or when user scroll down)